# Plotting multiple binary glm lines

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ggplot2

I'm trying to fit multiple lines on to one plot in R and I'c using code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942443/plotting-a-multiple-logistic-regression-for-binary-and-continuous-values-in-r
but I keep getting an error when trying to use predict function

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'type' not found

Code I'm using:

````
mouse.probit2<-glm(cbind(y,n-y)~type+rads,family=binomial(link="probit"),data=mouse.df)
newdata = expand.grid(rads=seq(0,800, length.out=100), rank=1:2)

newdata$prob = predict(mouse.probit2, newdata,type = "link")

ggplot(newdata, aes(rads, prob, color=factor(rank), group=rank)) +
  geom_line()
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Your glm model includes two predictors: **type** and **rads**. So your newdata should specify the values of these two predictors for which the model should produce predictions.

However, your newdata lists values for a predictor called **rank** (which is NOT included in your glm model!) and omits to specify values for the predictor **type** (which IS included in your glm model).

Because R can't find any values specified for **type** in newdata, it complains that object 'type' is not found. This is your clue that you need to revise your code so that the predictors featured in your glm model are also featured in newdata and likely in the ggplot.